# How does Messages determine whether the SEND button should be green or blue?

Tags: iphone, messages

When you send an SMS message to a turned off iPhone then check say an hour later and the SEND button is blue, does that mean the user at some point has switched on to check messages? Cause I tried to resend as iMessage and it went green again?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Is your question: How can I be certain my iMessage isn't send using SMS?
(I think the answer is: you can't)

Comment: @iDeveloper That's not right, as you can always switch off the **Send as SMS** under **Settings / Messages**.

Answer (score 2):

If the recipient's iMessage is **unavailable**, or yours, for that matter, the *Send* button will be turned to **Green**, showing that you'll send a **SMS**. When the iMessage service is **available** again, the button will be turned **Blue**, showing that you'll be sending iMessages instead of SMS.

So, if you want to make sure you'll always be sending an iMessage, although the service is unavailable, meaning that the recipient will receive the text whenever it's possible, just switch off the **Send as SMS** under **Settings / Messages**.